# How to get SheetID in SheetsService c#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

Thank you for reading it :) Im using Blazor server and Google.Apis.Sheets.v4. I am trying to delete columns in a sheet with this code:

```
serviceSheet = new SheetsService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
     HttpClientInitializer = credentialSheet,
     ApplicationName = ApplicitionNameSheet
});

 

public void DelteColumns(string ID, int start, int end)
    {
       
        Request RequestBody = new Request()
        {
            DeleteDimension = new DeleteDimensionRequest()
            {
                Range = new DimensionRange()
                {
                    SheetId = 0,
                    Dimension = "COLUMNS",
                    StartIndex = start,
                    EndIndex = end
                }
            }
        };

        List<Request> RequestContainer = new List<Request>();
        RequestContainer.Add(RequestBody);

        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest DeleteRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        DeleteRequest.Requests = RequestContainer;

        SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest Deletion = new SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest(serviceSheet, DeleteRequest, ID);
        Deletion.Execute();
    }
```

But for this I need SheetID for DeleteDimensionRequest. I have only 1 sheet in the spreadsheet, but his SheetID isnt 0. And I get error that there is no grid with index 0. I could not find a way to get the SheetId. Could you please help me? Maybe you can give me at least direction in which I can google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the API, but maybe I can help you.

You first need to get the [Spreadsheet](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet.html) object. Probably using [SpreadsheetResource.Get(...)](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.html#Google_Apis_Sheets_v4_SpreadsheetsResource_Get_System_String_) method.

Then you can use [Spreadsheet.Sheets](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet.html#Google_Apis_Sheets_v4_Data_Spreadsheet_Sheets) property to access individual sheets.

Then access the sheet properties: [SheetProperties.SheetId](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SheetProperties.html#Google_Apis_Sheets_v4_Data_SheetProperties_SheetId)

spreadsheet.[Sheets](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet.html#Google_Apis_Sheets_v4_Data_Spreadsheet_Sheets)[0].[Properties](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Sheet.html#Google_Apis_Sheets_v4_Data_Sheet_Properties).[SheetId](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SheetProperties.html#Google_Apis_Sheets_v4_Data_SheetProperties_SheetId)

If you need to find the spreadsheetId, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v3-api_4)